# Gmail and Facebook Profile-specific HTTPS: Vulnerable?

Tags: security, facebook, https

I've begun to wonder about something:

Given that Gmail and Facebook use HTTPS on a per-profile basis, and that they don't use it by default, are connections to them vulnerable?

I'm not familiar at all with the protocols involved, but my reasoning goes like this: the browser needs to figure out whether or not to use HTTPS, and by default, it doesn't. That means that whenever I point my page to Facebook.com, my browser sends some piece of information (perhaps a session ID?) over an *unencrypted* channel to Facebook, *before* figuring out whether or not I've requested HTTPS. (Please correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't believe it uses a secure connection for sending this.)

Doesn't this mean that anyone could hijack the session ID in the middle of the unsecure connection? Is this a potential vulnerability?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cookies that use the Secure flag are sent only via HTTPS. So it is possible to always redirect HTTP to HTTPS and avoid sending session cookies over HTTP before the redirection but I wouldn't count on it so I would never connect with Gmail using http://mail.google.com/ - only https://mail.google.com/

Actually I just checked and Gmail seems to set 6 cookies - only 3 of which are secure. When you visit http://mail.google.com/mail/ your browser actually sends your email address in cleartext for everyone to see before you get redirected to HTTPS.

As for the security of Facebook... I recommend watching the "How I met your girlfriend" talks by Samy Kamkar [at Defcon](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YDW7kobM6Ik) (shorter) and [at Blackhat](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O5xRRF5GfQs) (longer).

**Update to avoid confusion in the comments:** Samy Kamkar explained a method to **guess** the Facebook session cookie so HTTPS doesn't matter at all here. The point is that you can use HTTPS only and still be vulnerable to session hijacking.

Comment: Hm... two questions: (1) What about Facebook? I don't notice it doing any initial secure connections when it tries to connect over regular HTTP. (2) So that means that anyone eavesdropping on the network can see my email address whenever I type in `mail.google.com`, right?
Isn't that a bit... too unsafe?

Comment: Even if 3 of the 6 cookies do not have the secure bit set, it doesn't necessairly mean that your email address is exposed.  All connections to gmail are secured with SSL so the cookies are protected.  If you then browsed to www.google.com however, which is unencrypted while still logged in, your email would be sent in the clear.  Ever noticed your email address when searching google after reading gmail?

Comment: @Nick: What I said is that when you visit (http:) http://mail.google.com/mail/ your browser sends your email in cleartext before you get redirected to HTTPS. When you only go to (https:) https://mail.google.com/ then everything is ok. Unless you use (http:) http://www.google.com/ (as you point out) where your email is sent TO you by Google in cleartext... That's why you should always use (https:) https://encrypted.google.com/

Comment: Wow, although I'd always seen my email address when searching Google, I'd never realized that it's sent in cleartext! Interesting... I'm not using iGoogle again, thank you for pointing that out. :)

Comment: @Mehrdad: Yeah. Though sending an email to a cute girl using laptop in a cafe knowing her full name which is also sent by www.google.com is always a good conversation starter. "Hey isn't your name ...? I think I know you!" So thanks, Google. ;)

Comment: @Zed Not quite, look in the HTML source of the gmail login page.  You will notice that the action (location where it posts the data to) is HTTPS.  The data you type in on an unsecure page is sent securely.

Comment: @Mehrdad the www.google.com webpage only has the email address, not the real name.  If you make sure to logout of gmail before browsing to google you will be fine.

Comment: @Nick: I'm pretty sure about it because I just sniffed the traffic. Also I removed all mail.google.com cookies and after I securely log in to gmail I still get an insecure cookie with my email address, so when I visit (http:) mail.google.com/mail my browser sends my email in cleartext before I get redirected to HTTPS. I tested it.

Comment: @Nick: looking at the source of www.google.com I see my full name in the HTML - twice in fact.

Comment: @Zed, Ah, so you are logging into gmail, and while still being logged in you go to http://mail.google.com.  Yes, that is equivalent to going to www.google.com since they are both using the same TLD.  If you are not however logged into gmail and browser to http://gmail.com, type in your user/pass, check your email, and logout before browsing to any other *.google.com website not even your email address is exposed.

Comment: @Nick: I'm actually trying to protect my email address as well as my name... all while staying signed into Google in between browser sessions. :\

Comment: @Mehrdad, Ah, ok, there are two ways to do this but neither is ideal.  The first way is to use two different browsers i.e. firefox for gmail, chrome for everything else.  The second way is to use chrome's incognito mode for gmail since cookies assigned in incognito aren't available to other windows.

Comment: @Nick: Yeah... like you said, neither is ideal, lol. But thanks anyway. :)

Answer (score 2):

Both of these are secure and do not expose session IDs

1. User browses to http://www.facebook.com
2. User types in username and password which submits to https://www.facebook.com/...
3. The facebook servers have securely received the username/password from step 2, validate the user, and check the database to see if this user requests SSL only traffic.  If the user has SSL only traffic selected, facebook sets the secure bit in the cookie that contains the user's session ID only allowing it to be sent over secure connections.  All of the links facebook returns to that user are https:// links so each connection is encrypted.

   Nowhere in this process is the session ID exposed

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explicitly mention this: I'm assuming that the user is already logged in, so there's no username or password to send over HTTPS. In that case, why would anything (e.g. a session ID) use HTTPS at all?

Comment: Well, the user had to login sometime if they are already logged in, otherwise its turtles all the way down.

Comment: Huh? I'm not caring about the login moment, I'm caring about visiting the page *after* logging in, assuming the user never signs out. In those cases, does the Facebook session ID use HTTPS at all? (Why should it? The user might not have even requested it, so why should that be true? And wouldn't this be unsafe?)

Comment: @Nick: if the user is already logged in then he had to login OR guess the session ID (see the movies I linked in my post) so yeah it's sometimes turtles all the way down. ;)

Comment: Ah, ok, so you login, and then browse to http://www.facebook.com.  The sessionID is in a cookie that has a bit called the secure bit set so that your session ID cookie will only be sent over secure connections.  When you browse to http://www.facebook.com there is a secondary cookie without the secure bit that says to use https.  Facebook then redirects to https://www.facebook.com and then your browser can send the secure cookie with your session id

Comment: Ahh... the secondary cookie explains it. (I'm assuming there's no critical information in that one, right?) Thanks!

Comment: @Nick: I am talking about *guessing* the cookie here, not eavesdropping. Security of the connection is irrelevant. See the update to my answer.

Comment: Nope, it just says, this user is logged in securely, redirect to secure site.  Or it should